# Vue-Lottie and Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, lottie

Anyone get Vue-Lottie working with Nuxt? I tried to import it as Vue-Lotti said to:

`import Lottie from './lottie.vue';`

this says it cant find the package.

Then I tried how Nuxt had it:

`import Lottie from 'vue-lottie';`

this gives me an "Unexpected token <" error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `lottie-web` instead of `vue-lottie` with my VueJS apps and I had a similar problem to yours.

The way I made it work was to install it normally with `npm install lottie-web` and then call it in my components as: `import lottie from 'lottie-web/build/player/lottie';`.

Perhaps you have to also type in the path in the same manner with `vue-lottie`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use vue-lottie, you need to import the right lottie.vue component, located in your node_modules folder:

```
import Lottie from 'vue-lottie/src/lottie.vue'
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

I use lottie-web, simply install it with npm -> **npm install lottie-web**
or yarn -> **yarn add lottie-web**

Then create a file in your plugin folder -> **plugins/lottie.js** and add this
code:

```
import lottie from 'lottie-web';

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('lottie', lottie);
};
```

Finally register it in your nuxt.config.js :

```
plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/lottie', mode: 'client' }],
```

Now you can use lottie anywhere in your nuxt application
with **this.$lottie**.

See this code snipped to get you started:

```
<template>
  <div
      ref="animationElement"
      class="animation"
      @mouseover="open"
      @focus="open"
      @mouseleave="close"
      @blur="close"
    />
</template>
<script>
export default {
 mounted() {
    this.$lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: this.$refs.animationElement, // the dom element that will contain the animation
      loop: false,
      autoplay: false,
      path: 'your_path/lottie.json', // the path to the animation json
    })
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
        this.$lottie.setSpeed(1)
        this.$lottie.setDirection(1)
        this.$lottie.play()
    },
    open() {
      this.$lottie.setSpeed(1.5)
      this.$lottie.setDirection(-1)
      this.$lottie.play()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a working solution for `Nuxt 3` and `Composition API`:

**nuxt.config.ts:**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/lottie', mode: 'client' }],
})
```

**plugins/lottie.js:**

```
import lottie from 'lottie-web'
    
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => nuxtApp.provide('lottie', lottie))
```

**TheComponent.vue:**

```
<script setup>
    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();

    onMounted(() => {    
        nuxtApp.$lottie.loadAnimation({ ... });
```

Comment: I cannot really make it work. What should I add on the `<template>`?

Comment: You should insert the element ref to the `container` field of the parameter in the `loadAnimation`, for example:


```

<template>
<div id="menu-burger">
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {    
  nuxtApp.$lottie.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById('menu-burger'),
    name: 'menu-burger',
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    path: '/animations/menu-burger.json',
  });
}
</script>

```

Comment: In other words, the best and safe way is to dedicate an HTML element by id. For example, you can add a `<div>` with an `id` you can refer to in your `<script>` area. LIke this: `<template> <div id="menu-burger"> </template>`. 

And get it by standard `getElementById` function: `nuxtApp.$lottie.loadAnimation({ container: document.getElementById('menu-burger'), ... });`

Answer (score 1):

```
import lottie from 'lottie-web'
```

should work